# Почему Task<T> и Task не sealed?

Tags: c#, task

Почему майкрософт не убрали возможность наследования от Task и Task? Если не sealed, значит есть ситуации когда можно/правильно пронаследоваться от этого класса. Какие это могут быть в теории ситуации?

Comment: Откройте исходники или референс класса, посмотрите, какие там есть virtual методы, это и есть ответ на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задачи не запечатаны по той причине, что наследование от Task активно используется в недрах фреймворка. Вот примеры:

1. [`Task.CancellationPromise<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/64ce464f0137682db1007fd35b2fe01b0bc30191/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L2815) - задача, возвращаемая методом `Task<T>.WaitAsync`
2. [`Task.DelayPromise`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/64ce464f0137682db1007fd35b2fe01b0bc30191/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5601) - задача, возвращаемая методом `Task.Delay`
3. [`Task.WhenAllPromise`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/64ce464f0137682db1007fd35b2fe01b0bc30191/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5831) - задача, возвращаемая методом `Task.WhenAll`
4. [`Stream.ReadWriteTask`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/64ce464f0137682db1007fd35b2fe01b0bc30191/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs#L644) - задача, возвращаемая стандартными асинхронными методами потоков ввода-вывода

В принципе, от любого из этих наследников при желании можно избавиться, обойдясь внешним API (тот же WaitAsync неоднократно реализовывался разными костылями вокруг обычного API, а для всего остального есть TaskCompletionSource), однако использование особого внутреннего (internal) API совместно с наследованием позволяет коду из стандартной библиотеки аллоцировать меньше объектов.

Вспомним стандартный полифил для WaitAsync, чаще называемый WithCancellation:

```cs
        public static async Task WithCancellation(this Task task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            using (cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetResult(true), tcs))
            {
                if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);
                }
                await task; // already completed; propagate any exception
            }
        }
```

Он создаёт аж 4 новых объекта в куче: `TaskCompletionSource`, `CancellationTokenRegistration` (это не объект, но внутри объект всё равно есть), результат `WhenAny`, и конечный автомат для async-метода.

Создателям же `CancellationPromise` удалось обойтись только самим `CancellationPromise` и `CancellationTokenRegistration`.

Answer (score 2):

А зачем их запечатывать? Как наследование от тасков может их сломать (если специально не стараться)?

Практика в .NET, хоть и на первый взгляд нелогична, но такова:

1. Методы НЕ виртуальны по умолчанию
2. Классы НЕ запечатаны по умолчанию

`Task` и `Task<T>` просто следуют этой же практике.

На деле же, эта практика вполне логична. Вы ***можете*** хотеть запечатать класс, когда у вас есть более высокоуровневый класс с виртуальными методами, которые вы переопределяете в своем классе, но дальнейшее наследование от вашего класса не является каким-то логичным и/или довольно тривиальным.

Кейс наследования тоже довольно просто придумать. Если вам нужен какой-нибудь, например, `Task<Dictionary<MyClass, Dictionary<string, int>>`, то вы можете написать `MyTask : Task<Dictionary<MyClass, Dictionary<string, int>>` и сократить себе запись в коде.

Comment: *"Как наследование от тасков может их сломать (если специально не стараться)"* - если есть желание, добавите более конкретно описать как можно сломать?

Comment: По поводу виртуальности методов по умолчанию - помнится, Хейлсберг объяснял, почему в C# методы по умолчанию не виртуальны (в отличие от Java), и его доводы мне видятся вполне логичными: https://www.artima.com/articles/versioning-virtual-and-override

Comment: @Kalmankantaja учитывая, что `protected virtual` там только `Dispose()`, то без извращений с сокрытием методов через `new` сломать можно разве что его функциональность. Насколько это может быть критично можете посудить сами, глядя в исходник реализации: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,29d432e77814898d

Comment: @user11354240 спасибо за ссылку. Да, это вполне разумно. И вроде даже не противоречит моему ответу :)

Comment: @MaxS лучше референсы брать из source.dot.net (тут .NET самый новый и он напрямую с гитхаба вроде как), а в вашей ссылке на .net framework

Comment: @Kalmankantaja в core версии вроде бы вообще виртуального ничего нет в тасках. Но спасибо за дополнение.